# Prove if $x\gt3$ then $1\ge\frac{3}{x(x-2)}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I tried to prove it by contradiction.

Suppose it is not true that  $1\ge\frac{3}{x(x-2)}$, so  $1\lt\frac{3}{x(x-2)}$.  Then  $\frac{3}{x(x-2)}-1\gt0$.  Multiply both sides of $\frac{3}{x(x-2)}-1\gt0$ by ${x(x-2)}$.

$(\frac{3}{x(x-2)}-1\gt0)({x(x-2)}\gt0(x(x-2)$

${3-(x(x-2)\gt0}$

${3-x^2-2x\gt0}$

${-x^2-2x+3\gt0}$

${-1(x^2+2x-3)\gt0}$

$-1\frac{(x-1)(x+3)}{-1}\gt0/-1$

${(x-1)(x+3)\lt0}$

At this point I really do not know what to do after this point or if I really even went about it the right way.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You cannot multiply by $x(x-2)$ without possibly changing the inequality, if this is negative.

Comment: You are working too hard and thinking too little.  You can't multiply by $x(x-2)$ unless you know that $x(x-2) > 0$.  Which as $x > 3$ then $x-2 > 1$ so $x(x-2) > 3$ but.... If you do that you don't have to do *anything* else.  $x > 3$ so $x-2 > 1$ so $x(x-2) > 3$ so $\frac 3{x(x-2)} < \frac 33 = 1$.  ANd that's it!  You don't need to do any more.

Answer (score 6):

$x > 3
\implies x-2 > 1
\implies x(x-2) > 3
\implies 1 > \dfrac{3}{x(x-2)}
$

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x>3\implies x-2>1$ then $\dfrac1x<\dfrac13$ and $\dfrac1{x-2}<1$ so $$\frac3{x(x-2)}<\frac3{3(3-2)}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

From $$x-3\geq 0$$ follows:
$$x-1\geq 2$$
$$(x-1)^2\geq 4$$
$$x^2-2x+1\geq 4$$
$$x^2-2x\geq 3$$
$$x(x-2)\geq 3$$ so $$1\geq \frac{3}{x(x-2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make things more complex than they are?

The function $x(x-2)$ is *increasing* and *positive* on $(2,+\infty)$, hence 
$\;\dfrac2{x(x-2)}\;$ is *decreasing* and *positive* on this interval. 
Furthermore $f(3)=1$…